# Custom mechanism to switch to root user using playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

Till now I had been using `become: true` for running a task as root user (whenever required).

But this time the hardware I am trying to control is a bit different. Its a VM controlled by a different team, where the sudo operations are restricted. You are not allowed to do `sudo su` either. Simply, `sudo` is not permitted. 
In case you want to switch to a root shell, you have to execute a command (which maps to a binary) `sudo rootshell` (the only operation permitted with sudo). This is done in order to log sudo attempts.

Now, this fails my playbook as I cannot use `become: true` in case I want to install some package. Does ansible playbook provide any solution for this? I tried `shell: sudo rootshell` and failed, but even if it would have worked I don't feel the session will be maintained across tasks.

Comment: Give a try to `ANSIBLE_EXECUTABLE=rootshell` env when calling ansible-playbook.